# Проблема с запросом к БД в Symfony

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, symfony, dql

Сайт на symfony 3.4

Есть 2 таблицы:

product
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и category

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести информацию из этих таблиц в виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так, чтобы отображалось количество продуктов в каждой категории товаров

Написал вот такой DQL запрос:

```
    SELECT a.id, a.category, a.enabled, COUNT(b.id) as prcnt
    FROM AppBundle:Category a
    JOIN AppBundle:Product b WITH a.id = b.category
    WHERE a.enabled = :enabled
```

И в отладку вывел результат:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "category" => "Фантастика"
    "enabled" => true
    "prcnt" => "6"
  ]
]
```

Как видите нашлась только 1 категория, к томуже неправильно посчитал COUNT, в категории "Фантастика" 4 товара, а он посчитал вообще все товары - 6.

Где ошибка в моём DQL-запросе?
Почему на выходе только 1 категория?
Как правильно написать этот DQL-запрос?
И зачем в DQL ввели WITH вместо ON??

И вообще по best practice в symfony лучше писать DQL-запросы или использовать сборщик createQueryBuilder?

Comment: странный выбор алиасов для таблиц. почему не `p` и `c` ? и  где группировка, если предполагается использование агрегатов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отображения результатов по конкретной категории необходимо выполнить группировку. В данном случае:

```
SELECT a.id, a.category, a.enabled, COUNT(b.id) as prcnt
FROM AppBundle:Category a
JOIN AppBundle:Product b WITH a.id = b.category
WHERE a.enabled = :enabled
GROUP BY a.id
```